# docker-compose run env variable do not exists

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Do you know why the behavior of environment variables in docker run vs docker-compose run is handled differently?

When I look at the container after a docker-compose run with the docker-compose exec command, I cannot find my defined environment variables running the command "env".

```
$ a="test hello" docker-compose run -d app
$ docker-compose exec app
/code env
# HOSTNAME=ce1b4934lkj
# HOME=/
```

I thought the env variables would be available as long as the container is running.

Running the same test with docker run and docker exec, I get the expected result.

```
$ docker run --env a=tst --name alpy -dit alpine
$ docker exec -it alpy env
# a=tst
# HOME=/root
```

EDIT

If I use the docker-compose run syntax, the env variable is written to the container. But I don't understand why I can no longer see this env varialbe with my subsequent exec command. I am executing this command in the same container.

```
$ docker-compose run -e another=var -d app env
# /code env & exit
# another=var

$ docker-compose exec app
/code env
# HOSTNAME=ce1b4934lkj
# HOME=/
```

Comment: Your first command sets the environment variable `a` in the `docker-compose` process's environment, but absent an `environment:` section in the `docker-compose.yml`, it won't get passed into the container.  (Also try `a=tst docker run --rm alpine env`; it shouldn't be set there either.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for your helpful answer. that explains it. How can I write the env variable into the container without adapting the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: `docker-compose run` supports the `-e` [arg](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) just like `docker run`.  E.g. `docker-compose run -e a=b app env`.  You can also create a `.env` file which `docker-compose` will [read into the container environment by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) or you can provide the name of another environment file with `--env-file`.

Comment: @kthompso Thanks for the hint. I have expanded my question (EDIT section), because I don`t know why the env variable is only visible within the run command and not in the exec command.

Comment: Your `docker-compose exec app ...` is executing in a different container than the one you are expecting.  Most likely you created another container named `app` using `docker-compose up` or `docker run` and it's still running.  Inspect your running containers with `docker ps`, shut down the `app` container with `docker kill app` and then try again.  The container name will not be `app` if you start it with `docker-compose run` even if you specify `container_name` in the compose file.  The container name will be output by the `docker-compose run` command, or use `docker-compose ps` to find it.